# Inheriting keyword arguments using super(), but they are not listed untill specified in creating instance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, tkinter, keyword-argument

I have some trouble grasping this, I guess pretty simple, concept.
I am creating some tkinter app (not relevant), and I´m playing with inheriting attributes through super and *args, **kwargs:

```
class MainApp():

    def __init__(self, master = None, y = 10, x = "sample string"):
        self.master = master  
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
    # master is in the end root = tk.Tk(), 
    # which i pass as argument when creating that object, y and x are just for testing purpose

class Replica(MainApp):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        print(args)
        print(kw)
    # This is also just for testing how this stuff works, thing is;
    # When I run following code:


root = tk.Tk()
app = Replica(root)
print (app.x, app.y) # this returns ~ sample string 10; as expected
root.mainloop()

#But when output of print(args, kwargs) in Replica class __init__ method,
#it returns only (<tkinter.Tk object .>,) in printing args and empty dic
#{} in kwargs, therefore x and y werent considered either args or kwargs
# WHY?


#Well, but if i initialize Replica like this:

root = tk.Tk()
app = Replica(master = root, y = 5, x = "changed string")
root.mainloop()
# It returns empty tuple for args (), and full kwarg dic like this:
{'master': <tkinter.Tk object .>, 'y': 2, 'x': 'changed string'}

# In same logic, if I initiate Replica like this:


app = Replica(root, 10, "changed string")
# This returns all attributes in args, therefore print(args) in __init__
# method returns (<tkinter.Tk object .>, 10, 'changed string') 
# and kwargs are empty {}

# Similiarly, when running this:
app = Replica(root, 10, x = "changed string")
# It shifts x to kwargs dictionary and return is
# (<tkinter.Tk object .>, 10) and {'x': 'changed string'}
```

I mean I kind of understand what is going on, Im not blind, but still wonder, why master, y and x are not inherited as kwargs immediatly, after all, they are keyword arguments in MainApp **init** method. I would assume super() method will take care of that. Application works fine but I am kind of frustrated from not understanding this and would appreciate some insight.

How is x and y attribute inherited when..

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

.. does not specify x or y. And even when runnin this:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)
```

It runs fine and inherits x and y attributes..

Once again, I would appreciate some insight, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `super` or inheritance. It's just parameters taking on their default values when no arguments are passed. Here's a simple example:

```
def foo(x=5):
  print('foo: x =', x)

def bar(*args, **kwargs):
  print('bar:', args, kwargs)
  foo(**kwargs)

bar()
bar(x=2)
```

Output:

```
bar: () {}
foo: x = 5
bar: () {'x': 2}
foo: x = 2
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/IncredibleAjarPreprocessor)

`args` and `kwargs` are the values that are passed to `bar`, and in the end the same values are passed to `foo`. If nothing gets passed to `bar`, then nothing is passed to `foo`, and the default values are used.

`super().__init__(*args, **kw)` is equivalent to `MainApp.__init__(*args, **kw)`. The default values aren't being 'inherited', they're just being used as normal.

Comment: just for preventing some chaos, when initializing through parent, you need to add self to init as well, so MainApp.__init__(self, *a, **kw) is correct